Simple deform modifier making object thicker
I am trying to make animation of an object opening and closing using the simple deform modifier, but it is also causing the object to thickened. How can I only animate the opening and closing of this object without making it thick?

parent it to a chain of bones?

Would I have to animate by moving each individual bone? Or can add some procedural function on the chain of bones?

you can give a Copy Rotation constraint to each bone so that you only move one

For this particular use case, I found that if you make a chain of small bones then go to pose mode and change pivot to individual origins, then select all bones and rotate them to get the desired effect.

yes, even simpler than constraints
